# Accessing bearer token from axios

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, authorization, vuex

What code can I use to access a bearer token that's been stored in localStorage?

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1',
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'.
    Authorization: ???
  }
});
```

I'm having trouble sending auth headers using a axios Service. When I hardcode the existing bearer token it works, but how can I dynamically access that for each user as it changes?

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked! Thanks to DigitalDrifter for showing me the getItem function in localStorage.

I've been storing the bearer token in 'user' state, so I retrieved the object, parsed it, then inserted it into the Authorization header.

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const token = user.token;

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1',
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A [request interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) can be used to set the `Authorization` header prior to each outgoing request.

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('bearer_token')

    if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    }


    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```